# Non-Planar graph maximum degree proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

How can it be proved that a non planar graph has a maximum degree greater or equal than three?? 
 I have tried proving it by contradiction using the inequality m > 3n - 6 , but It is correct . I have thought of  mathematical induction but I am finding it difficult to prove this

Comment: What does a graph with a maximum degree of $2$ look like?

Comment: @MichaelBiro it could be a node on its own , two nodes connected with an edge and for degree 2 a triangle a square or a circle with as many nodes as we want

Answer (score 0):

Prove that a graph with maximum degree 2 is a disjoint union of paths and cycles (and isolated vertices). To do so: pick any vertex of degree 1 (if any), find its neighbor, check its degree. If 1, done, if 2, keep going until you (necessarily) hit another vertex of degree 1. That's a path. Once you've accounted for all vertices of degree 1, use a similar method to survey vertices of degree 2 and show that they all belong to cycles.

Now show that paths and cycles are planar, and the disjoint union of planar graphs is planar as well.

Comment: I have followed the tips for the first part of the proof. However I cannot prove the second part , that path and cycles are planar and disjoint union of planar graphs is planar. Can you give me a tip ?